# Bug report : Invalid "You've earned a bonus of 100 because we trust you on other sites of the network" notification

Tags: bug

Having, a long time ago, registered under Stack Overflow using `some_email_address`,
Then, under some site of the SE network using the same identity, SE site under which I earned some credit.

I then registered under U&L_SE using another identity : `another_email_address`

Yesterday, `another_email_address` being no longer valid, I removed it and added the original `some_email_address` to the list of logins as found under my U&L_SE profile settings.

I was then notified in my U&L_SE Recent Achievements drop down list that :

> UL +100 You've earned a bonus of 100 because we trust you on other
> sites of the network

100 credits which, as a matter of fact have not been credited.

---

Note : If it needed to be asserted : I am not complaining against the fact that my U&L_SE credit has not been increased. I do not even care reading the conditions in which this credit is due.
I'm only reporting some inconsistency.

Comment: Interesting; I'm not familiar with the details of the association bonus, but I wonder if it kept your `some_email_address` as the primary identity and thought it should award the association bonus, but a later section of that code realized you were already above 100? We'd have to ask someone on staff to look into your particular case further, I think.